# How to add text or characters using CSS (no javascript)?

Tags: html, css, tags

Well it should work in IE, I know IE doesnt support content property anything other that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only option is the the [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) property:

> The content property is used with the
>   `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, to
>   insert generated content.

But as you point out, this is part of CSS 3 and is not supported by IE.  In the meantime you will need to compensate by using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible to solve this without Javascript, using a combination of HTML and CSS. The trick is to duplicate the content added by the CSS in the HTML an IE-specific conditional comment (not shown by other browsers) and use the `display` CSS selector to toggle when that element is shown. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IE 8+ supports CSS `:after` and `content:`, so only IE 7 and below need to use a conditional comment.

Here is an example:

```
<style type="test/css" media="screen">
.printonly { display: inline; }
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
#maintitle:after { content:" \2014  Site Title";} /* for IE8+ and Other Browsers. sidenote: Can't use &mdash directly in generated content, so using escape code */
.printonly { display:inline } /* For IE <= 7 */
</style>

<h1 id="maintitle">Page Title 
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><span class="printonly">&mdash; Site Title</span><![endif]-->
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short of pictures of text — no.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [IE8.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to fix content, which might do the trick. If not, then there's nothing you can do besides background-image's with text

Answer (score 0):

The only way is JavaScript, or CSS3.

Maybe you could tell us what you need to do - then we can help.

Why can't you do it with js?